# Error when running LDAP query

Tags: vbscript, ldap, syntax-error

I'm getting an error when trying to execute a query using VBS

If I remove the `strWhereOU` portion of the query then it works, so the problem is somewhere in there, but I don't know where. Any pointer appropriated. Thanks.

I'm using this code to produce the query -

```
For i = 0 To Ubound(arrIncludeOU)
    arrIncludeOU(i) = "ADsPath LIKE '%OU=" & Trim(arrIncludeOU(i)) & "%'"
Next
strWhereOU = "AND (" & Join(arrIncludeOU, " OR ") & ") "

'** Set the query string and parameters *'
objCommand.CommandText = _
    "SELECT Name, operatingSystem, ADsPath, lastLogonTimeStamp " & _
    "FROM 'LDAP://" & strDomain & "' " & _
    "WHERE objectClass = 'computer' " & strWhereOU & _
    "ORDER BY Name"
objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = 2
objCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 30
objCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False

'** Execute the query *'
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
```

Here is the query that is being produced -

[image: VBS Query]

And here is the error that I am getting -

[image: VBS Error]

Answer (score 0):

The `LIKE %` is causing the problem, but so is the wildcard on the Adspath.

The appropriate wildcard use here is `='*'`, but it seems you can't do a wildcard search against the Adspath (or distinguishedName). You could use a wildcard on Name, CN or a variety of other attributes (`WHERE Name ='Smith*'`), but that wouldn't help you here.

You need to change your `FROM` location to something like this.

```
strOU = "OU=Sherborne Desktops,"
"FROM 'LDAP://" & strOU & strDomain & "' " & _
```

Read this page for more information http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692831.aspx

Comment: distinguishedName attribute type definitions generally do not include a SUBSTR matching rule. This is the reason a substring (not wildcard) assertion value cannot be used in those cases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately this does not work. I thought at first it may be because the OU in question was not top level, but even hardcoding that in to the query to test failed - `There is no such object on the server` (code 80040E37).

Comment: Apologies, it does work if I hard-code the rest of the OU path (but only if you spell the container names correctly!!!). The issue is that the user specifies the OU's to include, so this method, although valid, looks like it would not work in my case. Thanks.